# update Postgres psql prompt if semicolon is forgotten

Tags: mysql, postgresql

**tldr**: Can `psql` be altered to mimic the MySQL CLI w/ respect to improperly terminated statements?

In the MySQL CLI, when the user fails to properly terminate a statement, the prompt changes to indicate a semicolon was forgotten (indentation, adds `->`):

```
MariaDB[(none)]> describe testing123
  ->
```

The Postgres `psql` CLI prompt doesn't change if a semicolon is forgotten:

```
zach=# \dt
          List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  | Owner
--------+------------+-------+-------
 public | testing123 | table | zach
(1 row)

zach=# drop table testing123    
zach-# ;
DROP TABLE
zach=#
```

Instead, you just don't see the expected confirmation message (in this case, `DROP TABLE`). So it's not nothing, but sorta a catch-22 if you don't know what message you should be looking for or if there is even a confirmation message at all for the command you're running.

Comment: actually it does change,,, just not much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I settled on updating `.psqlrc` to mimic the MySQL CLI by adding: `\set PROMPT2 '   -> '`

If you want a clue from `psql` about where your statement went wrong, another option is `\set PROMPT2 '[more] %R > '` which tells you:

> whether psql expects more input because the command wasn’t terminated yet, because you are inside a /* ... */ comment, or because you are inside a quoted or dollar-escaped string [[ThoughtBot blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/improving-the-command-line-postgres-experience#changing-the-prompt-again)]

Answer (score 2):

```
\set PROMPT2 '-%# '
```

issue that at the start of your session, or you could add that to your `.psqlrc` file